# Defining a metric on an arbitrary norm

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and let $||.||$ be a norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$. I have shown that $D((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2))= ||(d(x_1,y_1),d(x_2,y_2))||$
is a metric on $X \times X$ when $||.||$ is the $l^1$ or $l^\infty$ norm.

I am now trying to understand whether this is in fact true for an arbitrary norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

So far, I have tried playing around with the norm axioms but I am getting nowhere. Can someone give me a hint for finding a counterexample or in fact proving that any norm will work. Thanks

Comment: Every normed space is metric space for the distance $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$.

Comment: It works for all norms that a) only depend on the modulus of the coordinates, that is $\lVert (x,y)\rVert = \lVert (\lvert x\rvert, \lvert y\rvert)\rVert$, and b) are monotonic in the sense that $\lvert x_1\rvert \leqslant \lvert x_2\rvert$ and $\lvert y_1\rvert \leqslant \lvert y_2\rvert$ implies $\lVert (x_1,y_1)\rVert \leqslant \lVert (x_2, y_2)\rVert$. This may give you an idea where to look for counterexamples.

Comment: @DanielFischer I have only just started learning about norms, so I am not aware of many examples of them. Could you elaborate on your hint?

Comment: @PierreCarre I am not sure what to make of this hint :(

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3039462/example-of-norm-on-mathbbr2-thats-not-absolutely-monotonic