# Properties of Norm in R^2

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

I have a question regarding properties of norm in $R^2$:

1. Does $Norm(x,y) = Norm(y,x)$ in general?
2. If $a, b, c ≥ 0$ and we have $a≥b$, how to prove $Norm(a,c) ≥ Norm(b,c)$?

These seems to be very basic questions about norms(not just $l_p$ norms, but any norm that satisfy the basic definitions) but I can't seem to prove/disprove them from the definitions. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you talking about the Euclidian norm? If so, then the second question follows because $a^2\geq b^2$ implies $\sqrt{a^2+c^2}\geq\sqrt{b^2+c^2}$.

Comment: Not Euclidean Norm, any general norm definition that would satisfy the axioms of norm.

Comment: Norms are not functions of two variables. Norms measure the length of a vector. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Definition

Comment: This is a fairly interesting question given that the usual norms $\|\cdot\|_p$ for $p \in [1, \infty]$ all satisfy this. +1

Comment: Yes I understand that, I meant any norm N: $R^2$ -> $[0, \infty)$ @parsiad

Comment: OP, this will be useful for the future: to address a specific user and make sure they get a notification for a message you want them to see, you'll want to use "@" followed by "nameofuser". For example here you'd add @parsiad. Typing the first characters will also let you autocomplete it so you don't have to type usernames like user24663357986 yourself, which is pretty neat.

Comment: Here's an answer to your second point: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3039468/1104384

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $Norm(x,y)=|x|+|2y|$ for 1.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p(\mathbf{x})=\Vert A\mathbf{x}\Vert$ where $\Vert\cdot\Vert$
is the Euclidean norm and $A$ is a $2\times2$ matrix with trivial
nullspace. Note that $p$ is a norm on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. You can
already easily construct cases in which $A$ is chosen to violate
property (1).